# Decrypt CryptoAPI SIMPLEBLOB in Java

Tags: java, c++, encryption, cryptoapi

Here is my process:

CryptoAPI:

1. Generate AES session key
2. Use recipient's public key to encrypt and export (1) in a SIMPLEBLOB
   with RSA
3. Send SIMPLEBLOB to recipient

Java:

1. Recipient receives (3)
2. Recipient wants to decrypt SIMPLEBLOB using his private key

This is pretty standard I believe. There is a need to byte reverse the received byte array (from step 4 above). However, for some reason, the number of bytes received is above the maximum allowable number of bytes that RSA algorithm can decrypt. The error is "javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 256 bytes". So there is something else going on that I don't understand. Can someone explain how to properly decrypt the SIMPLEBLOB in Java? Resources would help.

Comment: Have you seen http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375601.aspx#simp_BLOB ? The data produced by `CryptExportKey` contains a certain header, in addition to the actual cyphertext.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks I don't know how I missed that. So I would just strip out the "BYTE encryptedkey[rsapubkey.bitlen/8];" part from the SIMPLEBLOB, reverse the bytes, then decrypt it using RSA in Java.

Comment: How do you distribute the public keys? Is there a reason why TLS cannot be used here?

Comment: @ntoskrnl Suffice to say that I successfully imported the public key with CryptoAPI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this page: [SIMPLEBLOB structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee442763.aspx)
The first 12 Bytes of the blob belong to [BLOBHEADER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). To decrypt the key, start from the 12th position of the encrypted blob.

Comment: Yeah we solved this, see the comments on my question above. Thanks for answering though.